# Office Communicator: How to identify the opening of an IM window

Tags: c#, api, office-communicator

I'm developing an "automatic message" add-in for Office Communicator 2007, but I need to know how to identify if another user opens the IM Window (not me, but another user).

I have the following event:

```
private void communicator_OnIMWindowCreated(object pIMWindow)
{                     
    if ((chk_Enabled.Checked))
    {                
        IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced imWindow = pIMWindow as IMessengerConversationWndAdvanced;
        imWindow.SendText(TxtAutoMessage.Text);
    }
}
```

Is there a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately the Communicator Automation API doesn't support this directly. The only workaround I've found involves trapping the `OnIMWindowContactAdded` event.

For a conversation started by you, the following events fire in this order:

- `OnIMWindowCreated`
- `OnIMWindowContactAdded` (for yourself)
- `OnIMWindowContactAdded` (for the other participant)

For a conversation started by another participant, the following events fire in this order:

- `OnIMWindowCreated`
- `OnIMWindowContactAdded` (for the other participant)

So when the participant initiates the conversation, you don't see yourself added as the contact.

You could use this as follows

- On trapping `OnIMWindowCreated`, store the window handle (`pIMWindow.HWND`) in a dictionary (so you can handle multiple conversation windows)
- On trapping `OnIMWindowContactAdded`, look for the handle in the dictionary. If this is the first Added event you've seen for the window, the rule is: if the contact is you (`IsSelf`), then you started the conversation. Otherwise, another contact started the conversation.

It's not the most satisfactory solution (they never are when you work with the Automation API ;o) ), but it should get you there.